# Why do I receive intermittent I/O Errors that say "Couldn't open text file" when using pdftotext while looping through directories?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I have a bash script with a loop that uses pdftotext to convert many pdfs to text. Below is the relevant portion of the code:

```
cd /data/user/Data/Reports/pdf/
dirs=(A*/)
for directory in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    cd "/data/user/Data/Reports/pdf/$directory"
    files=(*.pdf)
    mkdir -p "/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/$directory"
    for file in "${files[@]}"
    do
        filePrefix=${file%.pdf}
        saveFilename="/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/$directory/$filePrefix.txt"
        pdftotext "$file" "$saveFilename"
    done
done
```

Most of the cases are successful, but many of them give me an error like the following and don't create the text file:

> I/O Error: Couldn't open text file '/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/AAL-US/AAL-US5_032.txt'

When I submit the following directly in the terminal, the pdf correctly converts to txt without any issues:

```
pdftotxt /data/user/Data/Reports/pdf/AAL-US/AAL-US5_032.pdf /data/user/Data/Reports/txt/AAL-US/AAL-US5_032.txt
```

The typical issue with this error is that I have misspecified the filepath, but I'm confident that isn't the case here as it works when I submit it directly through the terminal.

Why would it work for most file conversions and fail for some?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The error does not seem to happen for the same files every time. This time through, the code had no issues with AAL-US as in the error I first mentioned above. The text file ADSK-US8_032.txt does not exist. I just tried to convert this file to text directly in the terminal and it gave me the same error. And there is still space in the filesystem: inode use is at 54% and storage is at 60%. I have been working on my school's linux cluster and I did just learn that the cluster is having storage issue and giving "No space left on device" error - not sure if this is related.

Here is an excerpt from stdout stderr from what I ran last night:

> I/O Error: Couldn't open text file '/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/ADSK-US/ADSK-US8_032.txt'
> dirCounter=12/127; fileCounter=1919/1988; directory=ADSK-US/; filename=ADSK-US8_032.pdf; duration=0; datetime=06/24/20 22:31:31;

In case it is helpful, here is the full code I submitted:

```
cd /data/user/Data/Reports/pdf/
statusFile="/data/user/Projects/Reports/pdfTxtConversion/meta/pdf2textStatus.txt"
dirs=([A-C]*/)
totalDirs=${#dirs[@]}
dirCounter=1

for directory in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    echo "-------------------------------------------"
    echo "Processing directory $directory"
    echo "-------------------------------------------"

    cd "/data/user/Data/Reports/pdf/$directory"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "failed to cd to $directory from $PWD"
        exit 1
    fi  

    files=(*.pdf)
    totalFiles=${#files[@]}
    fileCounter=1

    mkdir -p "/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/$directory"
    for file in "${files[@]}"
    do
        startTime=`date +%s`
        filePrefix=${file%.pdf}
        saveFilename="/data/user/Data/Reports/txt/$directory$filePrefix.txt"    
        pdftotext "$file" "$saveFilename"   
        endTime=`date +%s`
        conversionDuration=$((endTime-startTime))
        msg="dirCounter=$dirCounter/$totalDirs; fileCounter=$fileCounter/$totalFiles; directory=$directory; filename=$file; duration=$conversionDuration; datetime=$(date +"%D %T");"
        echo $msg >> $statusFile
        echo $msg
        ((fileCounter++))
    done

    ((dirCounter++))

done
```

Comment: `...`? `//`? Are you sure you really mean those?

Comment: @Quasimodo I've edited to resolve your questions but it makes no change to the resulting error.

Comment: Please confirm the error says like `Reports/txt/AAL-US/AAL-US5_032.txt`. My point is you're using either absolute paths (starting with `/`) or names without `/` (from the expansion of `*.pdf`). It's strange a path starting with `Reports/` appeared.

Comment: As @KamilMaciorowski says, it's a bit strange that the error message arbitrarily removes `/data/user/Data` from the file's pathname. Is that the _complete_ error message?

Comment: That looks like it should be ok, you have a relative path as one argument to `pdftotext`, and an absolute path as the other, but they seem sensible. I might put the `/data/user/Data/Reports` part in a variable to keep from repeating it though.

Comment: Note that you seem to have edited the question a couple of times, first it used absolute paths, then tilde, then a relative path, and now the script has absolute paths but the error message has a relative path. That doesn't exactly help anyone else to understand what is going on. Run the script once, preferably with a small mock dataset, then post the exact contents of the script and the error messages. You could also use `set -x` in the script to have the shell print the commands it actually runs.

Comment: You might get a more detailed error messge with commands like `echo x > "$saveFilename" && rm -f "$saveFilename"` before `pdftotext "$file" "$saveFilename"`. This command should print something like `Permission denied` or `No such file or directory` instead of unspecific `I/O Error`.

Comment: Please verify that you still get the same error after your various edits. Then, if you still have issues, let us know if the text output files that you're having issues with already exists or not (and if they do, what the permissions and ownership on them and their parent directories are), and whether you have any space left on the filesystem that you're trying to write to.

Comment: So, about your last edit where you mention that the school's system might have had an issue with disks running out of space: Yes, this could be related. If it is, then it's a temporary issue and not at all related to your code (which me and others think looks ok).